# Mysql (5.5) precision issue with function SUM with decimal field

Tags: mysql

Simple precision issue with mysql list of numbers do not calculate the same with sum as a single calculation. (How does one handle this senario?) There is a one(1) cent difference?

Sample of rows:

```
Select qty, (qty*21.25)
6.5  | 138.125
0.5  | 10.625
0.5  | 10.625
0.25 | 5.3125
1    | 21.25
2    | 42.5
1    | 21.25
2    | 42.5
2.5  | 53.125
2.5  | 53.125
2    | 42.5
3    | 63.75
3    | 63.75
3.5  | 74.375
```

Sample 2:

```
Select sum(qty), sum(amount)
30.25 | 642.8175
```

Sample 3:

```
Select 30.25*21.25
642.8125
```

`Since the answer was so vague. Let try this. Can anyone explain why the mysql statement produces the wrong results.`
`SELECT 6.875+3.125
10.00`
`Shouldn't this be
10.01`

Answer (score 0):

Read this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html).  Floating point numbers are not stored as exact values, therefore could be problems with calculation precision